# Different between Android TV and Google chromecast

Tags: android, chromecast, android-tv

As an Android developer, I would like to know the difference between
Android TV and Chromecast. Both the technical and functional details
would be fine. I have a native app for both tablet and phone. I would
like it extend it to TV. Which is the best to device to buy: Android TV
or Chromecast?

I am little confused about it.

I have already read about Leanback Library and stuffs.

But I am confused about which device to choose for developing apps for
TV.

Kindly recommend where to start.

Comment: Depends on what your app does and what you mean by "extend it to TV". Chromecast is really just a passive receiver of content - mostly media streams, but there are exceptions that use the big screen in other ways - and always depends on a phone or tablet for control. AndroidTV, OTOH, runs a complete Android OS (and you can just upload any APK and run it), and does not depend on a phone. It has it's own remote and you can connect game controllers, too. The leanback support lib is just a collections of views (Activities, Fragments) that make it easy to build something acceptable. Anything else?

Comment: Extends means i need a app built for TV either using chromcast or android-tv..
Can apk be installed in chromcast device? ..Becoz i also saw chromcast apps here..
https://www.google.com/intl/de_de/chromecast/apps/?utm_source=chromecast.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As a android-developer I would like to know the difference between
>   android-tv and chrome cast.

**TL;DR.1: Android TV is actually Android. Chromecast is simply a way to *extend* an existing application.**

The key difference between Android TV and Chromecast is their functionality. Android TV is another attempt at a device (either built in to a regular TV, or something like a set top box) that you pair with a TV that essentially turns your TV into a big Android tablet without a touch screen. Android TV is Android, written in Java and XML, just on a different form factor. Chromecast, however, is meant to help extend your existing app, rather than actually run the app itself. Chromecast is almost entirely utilized to extend your app's media experience (if one exists) or perhaps display something like a game board if your app lends itself to that use-case. I believe their are APIs to work with Chromecast using only Java (CastDisplay or something similar) but I've only personally experienced interactions with it using Javascript running on a backend.

> I have a native app for both tablet and phone.I would like it extend
>   it to TV, Which is the best to device to buy android-tv or chromocast
>   [sic].

**TL;DR.2: If your app simply has media, go Chromecast. If your app is a game or something similar that lends itself to the big scree, go Android TV.**

As always, this answer depends on what your app is. You didn't mention anything about it in your question. If your app contains media content that you'd just like to display on a Television, I'd highly recommend looking into Chromecast. If, however, you have a rich experience that would be enhanced by potentially having the user play an interactive game in, say, their family room, then I would recommend Android TV.

Answer (score -2):

When the user wants a stand-alone device

Then he wants android-TV

.

When the user wants a cheap companion device

Then he wants a chromecast